# Efficient List comprehension with multiple conditions using shift?

Tags: python, beginner, time-limit-exceeded, pandas

I am new to python.

I am trying to get the total number of failures by checking first how did the transition of the column Failure Sensor. Then creating the Start column from devicetimestamp if the next value of Failure Sensor is equal to the value and finally getting the count when the values are true and ignoring the empty timestamps.

**The code works perfectly but on a very small dataset.**

**I am trying to execute this code on a dataset containing 300,000 rows and it is taking too long. Please note that this code is also being used to get the number of faults of several columns. So the execution time will take more in this case**

Is there a way to improve this code or to get the same results in a different approach in an efficient way ?

```
data = {'deviceTimestamp' : ['2022-08-21 00:00:04.019345800','2022-08-21 00:00:09.666780800',
                             '2022-08-21 00:00:15.193316200','2022-08-21 00:00:20.708187',
                             '2022-08-21 00:00:26.212871600','2022-08-21 00:00:31.792147900',
                             '2022-08-21 00:00:37.345935900','2022-08-21 00:00:42.855598900',
                             '2022-08-21 00:00:48.380273','2022-08-21 00:00:53.894567100',
                             '2022-08-21 00:00:59.421452300','2022-08-21 00:01:04.994086700',
                             '2022-08-21 00:01:10.549778100','2022-08-21 00:01:16.067442300',
                             '2022-08-21 00:01:21.585345300','2022-08-21 00:01:27.123348',
                             '2022-08-21 00:01:32.657100400','2022-08-21 00:01:38.681526500',
                             '2022-08-21 00:01:44.254180800','2022-08-21 00:01:49.832247900',
                             '2022-08-21 00:01:55.404809800','2022-08-21 00:02:00.935254300',
                             '2022-08-21 00:02:06.456698200','2022-08-21 00:02:12.023842500',
                             '2022-08-21 00:02:17.601805600'],
        'Failure_Sensor' : [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
       }
df_failure_sensor = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor_Transition'] = [(df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i] if df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'].shift(1)[i] != df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i]
                                          else (df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i] if((df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'].shift(-1)[i] != df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i])) 
                                          else ""))
                                          for i in range(0, len(df_failure_sensor))]
df_failure_sensor = df_failure_sensor[df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor_Transition'] != ""]
df_failure_sensor.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df_failure_sensor["Start"] = [(str(df_failure_sensor['deviceTimestamp'][i]) if df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'].shift(-1)[i] == df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i] else "")
                                                    for i in range(0, len(df_failure_sensor))]
number_of_faults = df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][(df_failure_sensor['Start'] != "") & (df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'] == True)].count()
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please [edit] your question so that the title describes the *purpose* of the code, rather than its *mechanism*.  We really need to understand the motivational context ("*why*" more than "*how*") to give good reviews.  Thanks!

Comment: Does this code even work? You have five sensor failures but this reports only three

Answer (score 0):

Without even materially changing anything, the indentation of this code is impenetrable, and I had to do this to have any idea what the code is doing:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'deviceTimestamp': [
        '2022-08-21 00:00:04.019345800','2022-08-21 00:00:09.666780800',
        '2022-08-21 00:00:15.193316200','2022-08-21 00:00:20.708187000',
        '2022-08-21 00:00:26.212871600','2022-08-21 00:00:31.792147900',
        '2022-08-21 00:00:37.345935900','2022-08-21 00:00:42.855598900',
        '2022-08-21 00:00:48.380273000','2022-08-21 00:00:53.894567100',
        '2022-08-21 00:00:59.421452300','2022-08-21 00:01:04.994086700',
        '2022-08-21 00:01:10.549778100','2022-08-21 00:01:16.067442300',
        '2022-08-21 00:01:21.585345300','2022-08-21 00:01:27.123348000',
        '2022-08-21 00:01:32.657100400','2022-08-21 00:01:38.681526500',
        '2022-08-21 00:01:44.254180800','2022-08-21 00:01:49.832247900',
        '2022-08-21 00:01:55.404809800','2022-08-21 00:02:00.935254300',
        '2022-08-21 00:02:06.456698200','2022-08-21 00:02:12.023842500',
        '2022-08-21 00:02:17.601805600'
    ],
    'Failure_Sensor' : [0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0]
}
df_failure_sensor = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor_Transition'] = [
    (
        df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i]
        if df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'].shift(1)[i] != df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i]
        else (
            df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i]
            if ((df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'].shift(-1)[i] != df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i]))
            else ""
        )
    )
    for i in range(0, len(df_failure_sensor))
]
df_failure_sensor = df_failure_sensor[df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor_Transition'] != ""]
df_failure_sensor.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)
df_failure_sensor["Start"] = [
    (
        str(df_failure_sensor['deviceTimestamp'][i])
        if df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'].shift(-1)[i] == df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][i]
        else ""
    )
    for i in range(0, len(df_failure_sensor))
]
number_of_faults = df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'][
    (df_failure_sensor['Start'] != "") &
    (df_failure_sensor['Failure_Sensor'] == True)
].count()
```

Once that's done, the worst offender in the code is generators with ternaries. That's not how Pandas is supposed to work and is a basic failure to vectorise. In a bit I'll post an example vectorisation.

Comment: So the code does work? You're not answering an off-topic question?

Comment: @pacmaninbw I noticed the discrepancy after I posted my answer. Waiting on OP to see what's up.

Comment: @Reinderien so how is it possible to do this code faster ? In a much efficient way ? Is there a different way to achieve the same result ? The problem that I am facing is that I am testing this code on a 200,000 rows and the same code is being executed 5 times for 5 different faults so it is taking a lot of time.

Comment: @Noobie1997 yes, but we need answers to the comments on the question above

Comment: @Reinderien Which comments do you mean ? The code works fine. The result is always 3. I need to achieve the same result but in a more efficient way. Is there something else that you would like to know ?

Comment: Why are there only three failures detected? Is it because rows with only one failure timestamp are ignored?

Comment: @Reinderien exactly. Is there a possibility to make it better ?

Comment: Yes, but you need to edit your question to describe that logic and then we need to vote to reopen it